# How can i pass a property to a directive on vue js?

Tags: javascript, frontend, vue.js, web-frontend

how can i get the property value on a `v-show` or `v-if` directive? i've already try to pass like the example bellow but not succeed.

`v-show="cabin >= {{ number }}" number="5"`

i'm stuck with this and since vue.js it's kind of new its so hard to find documentation and examples.

Comment: Where are `cabin` and `number` defined in? Please provide your Vue.js codes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Vue Components, then you could do something like this:

```
Vue.Component('my-comp', {

    template: '#my-template',

    props: [
        'number',
    ],
    data: function(){
        return{
            cabin: 4
        };
    }
}):
```

and then in your view, use it like this:

```
<my-comp v-show="cabin >= number" number="5"></my-comp>
<template id="my-template">
    <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you used a custom attribute (`number`), I guess that you used a component.

So, as he said @user3324298, you need something like this:

```
Vue.Component('my-comp', {
  template: '#my-template',

  props: ['number'],

  data: function() {
    return {
      cabin: 4
    }
  }
})
```

But the template, should be something like this:

```
<template id="my-template">
    <div v-show="cabin >= number" number="5">
        <div>Lorem Ipsum</div>
    </div>
</template>

<my-comp></my-comp>
```

`v-show` should be into the scope of component.